# Creating new classes on code execution

Tags: java, class, singleton

Trying to make code to work with this main:

```
// TestClass class ResselerTest {

   public int ValueOfContainer(Object conatiner, carmodel) {        //have to count value of Mazda cars

}




  public static void main(String[] args) {


    Reseller Joe = new Reseller();

                    //name   cash in k's
    Customer John = new Customer("John", 200); 


    John.get(new Ford(5)); // (i) no of cars. John want to buy 5 ford's
    John.get(new Ferrari(5));
    John.get(new Mazda(3));


    ShoppingCart JohnCart = John.getShoppingCart();
    System.out.println("Before payment\n" + JohnCart);

    // Hes paying right now!

    John.pay();

    System.out.println("Paid\n" + John.getShoppingCart());


    System.out.println("John got : " + John.getCash() + " USD");

    // Now we need to pack them into container
    Container JohnContainer = new Container(John);
    janek.pack(JohnContainer);

    // After packing to conainer. 
    System.out.println("After packing to conainer\n" + John.getShoppingCart());

    // Check whats in container

    System.out.println(JohnContainer);

    // Lets see how much John paid for white cars.
    System.out.println("White cars cost: " +
                        valueOf(JohnContainer, "white") );

       } }

// ---------------------------------------------------------------

class Reseller {

  public Reseller() {
    // PriceList Singleton!!!
    PriceList pl = PriceList.getInstance();
    pl.set("Ford", 24);
    pl.set("Ferrari", 120);
    pl.set("Mazda", 9);    //price in k's   }

}

//---------------------------------------------------------------

public class Customer {     String name;    int cash;
            public Customer(String name, int cash)  {this.name = name; this.cash = cash;

    }

    public }

//---------------------------------------------------------------

public class ShoppingCart( {    //public ShoppingCart   // no idea


}


//---------------------------------------------------------------


public class PriceList {        public static PriceList instance = null;    HashMap<String, Integer> prices = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    public static PriceList getInstance() {         if (instance == null) {             instance = new PriceList();         }       return instance;    }

    public void set(String car, int value){ 

        prices.put(car, value);

    }



        // singleton

    public PriceList() {

            }



}
```

My main problem.
How to make `John.get(new Mazda(3));` to work `<sic!>`
And how to link cars to color. As far was sad that 1 car have 1 color `(Ferrari => ofc. Red :))`

I will appreciate any help from you fellows.

Comment: Did you mean "code execution" ? :)

Comment: Yeah xD Im little exhaused. 18h of programming in C# now I have to make this with java.

Comment: bwaha, sounds like lot of fun! ;D

Answer (score 0):

It appears that get() doesn't work because you haven't written this bit yet.  I suggest you try to write this method (at least the declaration)

It appears you need a structure/class which associates Car and Color.

I suggest you use camelCase for variable names.

Comment: Got just PriceList and Customer.
I have no idea how to use "new Ford(40);" etc.
Easy to pack them in container just arraylist

Comment: Personally I would make Car an enum for which FORD is an instance.  I would allow John to add a orders like `addOrder(5, Color.RED, Car.FORD);`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something rather wrong with your object model.

- It appears that you have a class for each model of Car.  I'd have thought that where needed to be a single Car class, which had attributes such as "model", "color", "price" and so on.
- It appears that an instance of (say) `Ferrari` is supposed to represent a number of cars, rather than a single Car.

I'm not going to tell you exactly how to implement this, since it looks like homework to me.

Comment: Its homework from the University but for next year. Im trying to learn it now That why im doing That kind of exercises.

Comment: Your enthusiasm is commendable, but I believe that you will learn better if we don't spoon-feed you with answers.  Can I suggest that you get a copy of the recommended text book for the course ... and read through the chapters on object oriented *design*.

Comment: BTW - trying to learn new stuff after 18 hours of programming sounds like a REALLY BAD IDEA.  Go to bed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all get Object Oriented concepts clear. What is a person to car relationship.

Secondly, `John.get(new Mazda(3))` is not a very good program. The method names should indicate what they do. Here get method is used for actually setting the purchase made by that customer. John buys 3 Mazdas when we call `John.get(new Mazda(3))` Is that understanding correct?

The advantage of OOP is that we can map real world entities and talk in real world terminologies in our program. So something like `makePurchase(..)`, `submitOrder(..)`, `checkOut(..)` would make sense.

It is often said that the programming language helps us think. (sometimes they limit our thoughts :))

Also, a good OO design will say something like a Customer class has a method:
`checkOut(Set cars)` instead of

```
checkOut(Honda[] hondaCars)
```

Does this help?

Comment: Thank Vladimir for your answer.
The main conecept of this exercise is to make TestClass to work. 

I do alot of multiclass programming in C# but in this case of buisness logic Im confused.